# Entity Framework - code first, remove field without schema change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on a solution that uses the entity framework code first approach:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("itemId")]
    [Index("idx_item_id")] 
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ItemId{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("otherId")]
    [Index("idx_other_id")]
    public long OtherId{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("randomStuff")]
    public string RandomStuff{ get; set; }
}
```

And is directly mapped as:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("name=DataContext")
    {
        Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items{ get; set; }
```

So basically I have XMLs coming in and these are directly mapped with the model. A HTTP POST comes in, xml is deserialized using the model and then directly inserted to the database. Now I am no longer interested in a field `RandomStuff`, but I don't want to change the schema, I would simply start inserting `NULL`s there. Would it make sense to write something like:

```
    private string _randomStuff;
    [XmlElement("randomStuff")]
    public string RandomStuff
    {
        get { return _randomStuff; }
        set
        {
            _randomStuff = null;
        }
    }
```

Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing of course is to bite the bullet and change the schema. But I know there can be many reasons not to do that (just yet).

A better option (then the `null` assignment in the setter) is to use a private setter:

```
public string RandomStuff { get; private set; }
```

EF can handle private setters and by doing this, EF will never think the property has changed (because it reads a different value than the one it was set with) and fire useless updates. And you will still be able to read old content.

If you don't want to display the content, even if it's still there, I'd replace the *mapped* property by a new dummy property (again with a private setter) and mark the *current* property as not mapped.

Comment: The second approach works. First one does not because I am using the same class for XML deserialization and I can't deserialize if a field has no public setter.